# after_update trigger event before update rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following update action in my controller. The issue I am facing here is that, I want to send an email to the User when accepted_offer_letter is true. In the update action I am updating the accepted_offer_letter to true. But the issue I am facing here is send_offer_email runs but if I check the value of accepted_offer_letter it still return false due to which emails are sent out. But in the console I checked accepted_offer_letter is true. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
accepted_offer_letter: true
```

users_controller.rb

```
def update
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @user_params = user_params
  @user = current_user
  @user.assign_attributes(@user_params)
  if @user.finalize_change
    generate_offer_letter
  end
  render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity unless @user.save
  end
end


private
def generate_offer_letter
 @user.assign_attributes(accepted_offer_letter: true)
end
```

user.rb model

```
after_update: send_letter


def send_offer_email
 binding.pry_remote
 if accepted_offer_letter
  UserMailer.send_offer_letter(id).deliver_now
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of **transaction block of ActiveRecord**.

During an `after_save` or `after_update` hook, the object in the database is not updated yet. It appears to be updated when you inspect from the same thread as the transaction. However, the transaction is not yet committed. The transaction is a wonderful design decision, but it can lead to some surprising behavior with `after_save` or `after_update`

For more read this article which explained with good examples : https://flexport.engineering/how-to-safely-use-activerecords-after-save-efde2b52baa3

**Note** : -
A quick fix for the above issues is to use `after_commit` instead of `after_save` or `after_update`. Using `after_commit` guarantees that you will have a permanent state of the database.

Comment: Well Said @code_aks
Nit pick: after_commit is trigger when an record is created, update or destroyed you have to use like
after_commit :method_name, on: :update